# Под какой лицензией распространяются RFC документы?

Tags: лицензирование, документация, стандарт, авторские-права, rfc

Под какой лицензией распространяются RFC документы? Она одна или их несколько? И какие ограничения она(и) накладывает(ют) на распространение и/или перевод этих документов?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052027/what-licence-do-rfcs-have